# Free styling themes Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm looking for free themes to style my private Xamarin.Forms application which has a non commerical purpose. I tried Syncfusion already, but they let me to create a whole new application which I don't like.

I want to look my application a bit nicer than the standard look and feel.

Comment: You can use the Syncfusion items seperately like only the buttons or etc. Are you looking for Templates

Comment: Or take a look here , you can donwload them see how it works and use the items of page you like . https://awesomeopensource.com/project/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-goodlooking-UI?categoryPage=15

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms applications can respond to style changes dynamically at runtime by using the **DynamicResource** markup extension.

For more detail, you can refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/theming